# How to remove a sub child of an xml file using python?

Tags: python, xml

I have an xml file, which has a particular set of child lines which should be deleted when the python code is run.

Below shown lines are my xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<visualization protocolVersion="10.4.0.0">
  <globalSection/>
  <coreObjectDefinition type="displayDefinition">
    <version type="version" value="10.4.0.0"/>
    <width>1920</width>
    <height>810</height>
    <referenceCheck>2</referenceCheck>
    <defaultBgColor type="colorSet" r="255" g="255" b="255"/>
    <defaultFgColor type="colorSet" r="0" g="0" b="0"/>
    <defaultFont type="font" name="Tahoma" size="16" underline="false" strikethrough="false"/>
    <defaultStroke type="stroke" width="1.0"/>
    <grid type="grid" gridVisible="true" snappingActive="true" verticalSnapInterval="8" horizontalSnapInterval="8" onTop="false">
      <color type="colorSet" r="0" g="0" b="0"/>
    </grid>
    <revisionHistory type="revisionHistory">
      <revision type="revision" who="ADMIN" when="2020.05.03 09:46:15.566 CEST" what="Created" where="CPC-A0668-4138"/>
    </revisionHistory>
    <blinkDelay>500</blinkDelay>
    <mousePassThrough>false</mousePassThrough>
    <visibilityGroup type="componentData">
      <htmlId>2</htmlId>
      <name>Overview</name>
      <description>Always shown</description>
      <minimumZoomEnabled>true</minimumZoomEnabled>
      <minimumZoomFactor>10.0</minimumZoomFactor>
    </visibilityGroup>
    <visibilityGroup type="componentData">
      <htmlId>3</htmlId>
      <name>Rough</name>
      <description>Shown when viewing viewing a large area</description>
      <minimumZoomEnabled>true</minimumZoomEnabled>
      <minimumZoomFactor>25.0</minimumZoomFactor>
    </visibilityGroup>
    <visibilityGroup type="componentData">
      <htmlId>4</htmlId>
      <name>Standard</name>
      <description>Shown when using the default view setting</description>
      <minimumZoomEnabled>true</minimumZoomEnabled>
      <minimumZoomFactor>100.0</minimumZoomFactor>
    </visibilityGroup>
    <visibilityGroup type="componentData">
      <htmlId>5</htmlId>
      <name>Detail</name>
      <description>Shown only when viewing a small area</description>
      <minimumZoomEnabled>true</minimumZoomEnabled>
      <minimumZoomFactor>400.0</minimumZoomFactor>
    </visibilityGroup>
    <visibilityGroup type="componentData">
      <htmlId>6</htmlId>
      <name>Intricacies</name>
      <description>Shown only when viewing a very small area</description>
      <minimumZoomEnabled>true</minimumZoomEnabled>
      <minimumZoomFactor>1000.0</minimumZoomFactor>
    </visibilityGroup>
    <visualizationLayer type="componentData">
      <htmlId>1</htmlId>
      <name>Layer1</name>
    </visualizationLayer>
    <componentCountHint>1</componentCountHint>
    <ellipse type="componentData" x="851.99896" y="300.00006" top="92.000046" bottom="91.99985" left="99.99896" right="100.001526">
      <htmlId>7</htmlId>
      <stroke type="stroke" width="1.0"/>
      <fillPaint type="paint">
        <paint type="colorSet" r="255" g="255" b="255"/>
      </fillPaint>
      **<data type="data">
        <action type="actionConnectTo">
          <property type="property" name="ellipse.visible"/>
          <filter type="filter">
            <value>0.0</value>
          </filter>
          <connection type="connection">
            <direction>1</direction>
            <itemName>AOG.Templates.Alarm</itemName>
            <itemId>2.1.3.0.0.2.1.8</itemId>
          </connection>
        </action>
      </data>**
    </ellipse>
  </coreObjectDefinition>
</visualization>
```

I want only the below part to be deleted from the entire xml file.

```
    <data type="data">
       <action type="actionConnectTo">
         <property type="property" name="ellipse.visible"/>
         <filter type="filter">
           <value>0.0</value>
         </filter>
         <connection type="connection">
           <direction>1</direction>
           <itemName>AOG.Templates.Alarm</itemName>
           <itemId>2.1.3.0.0.2.1.8</itemId>
         </connection>
       </action>
     </data>
```

The below mentioned python code only removes the child section and not the sub child.. Kindly help me out on this

```
    from xml.etree import ElementTree
    root = ElementTree.parse("test1.xml").getroot()
    b = root.getchildren()[0]

    root.remove(b)
    ElementTree.dump(root)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,utils,req
html = '''Your xml'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
data = doc.select('data@type=data') # Get the element
data.repleaceSelf("") # Remove it
print(doc.html) # This is what you want
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't access sub-child of an element using ElementTree. Each node only has "pointers" to the direct children of it. So, in order to access the `<data/>` node and remove it, you should refer to it from its direct parent node.

I'd do it in this way:

```
for d in root.findall('coreObjectDefinition'):
    for e in d.findall('ellipse'):
        for f in e.findall('data'):
            e.remove(f)
```

This library has syntax that allows you to search a tree recursively, so you're able to find the element with `root.findall('.//data')`. So a shorter version of the above code would be:

```
for d in root.findall('.//ellipse'):
    for e in d.findall('data'):
        d.remove(e)
```

Comment: "you can't access sub-child of an element using ElementTree". That is not true. You can use `elem.find("child/subchild")`, for example.